# Редирект из CanActive ломает маршрутизацию

Tags: angular2

В общем, делал все по [этому](https://webformyself.com/problemy-zashhity-routa-v-angular/) примеру и получил такой guard:

```
@Injectable()
export class CanActivateAdd implements CanActivate, OnDestroy {


     path: ActivatedRouteSnapshot[];
     route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot;
     _sub: Subscription;
     constructor(private _permissions: PermissionService, private _router: Router) {
          this._sub = this._router.events.pipe(filter(event => event instanceof NavigationCancel))
               .subscribe(event => {
                    if (this._router.url === '' || this._router.url === '/') {
                         this._router.navigate(['home']);
                    }
               });
     }

     canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot
     ): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
          let roles = route.data.roles as Array<Permissions>;
          return this._permissions.can(roles[0]);
     }
     ngOnDestroy(): void {
          this._sub.unsubscribe();
     }
}
```

Суть в том, что если юзер решит перейти руками на запрещенный маршрут, то его должно редиректнуть не на пустую страницу, а на главную.

Контент отображается правильно, но проблема в том, что в адресной строке красуется только адрес приложение и отсутствует сегмет home, в следствии чего, как я понимаю, ломается маршрутизация и при попытке перейти по маршрутам, которые ранее работали оборачиваются такой ошибкой:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot activate an already
>   activated outlet Error: Cannot activate an already activated outlet

Как можно пофиксить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте аналогично сделать:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private router: Router, private authService: AuthService<User>) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            if (state.url !== '/') {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(`/login?redirectUrl=${encodeURIComponent(state.url)}`);
            } else {
                this.router.navigateByUrl(`/login`);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, твой вариант работает. А в чем косяк моего кода?

Comment: В том, что ты проделываешь это в кострукторе, в момент создания этого класса.

Comment: Ну так-то я в конструкторе делаю только подписку, которая сработает в будущем. Нет?

Comment: Я так понимаю, у Вас в каждом гварде такая конструкция?

Comment: Гвард только 1, но данный гвард на нескольких маршрутах.

Comment: За ошибку я вам врядли расскажу, сейчас. Надо сидеть внимательно разбираться :(